# Passing data from one state to another state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({
        id: null,
        created_date: "2021-02-18",
        classroom:"",
        name: "",
});
```

i want to pass the create_date value to anther state

```
const [notify, setNotify] = useState({
        id: 5,
        created_by: "1",
        notification:"object added",
        received_date:created_date,
});
```

here, i want that created_date value in received_date

Comment: You'll need to provide more context for this if you want useful answers.

Comment: @pilchard , object data are fetched from html form, and i need to pass that data into another state.

Comment: use `received_date:object.creadted_date,`?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to useEffect for that since `object` will mutate over time, and `notify` has to keep up with that.

```
const initialObject = {
        id: null,
        created_date: "2021-02-18",
        classroom:"",
        name: "",
}

const [object, setObject] = useState(initialObject);

const [notify, setNotify] = useState({
        id: 5,
        created_by: "1",
        notification:"object added",
        received_date:initialObject.created_date,
});

useEffect(()=>{
   setNotify(notify => ({...notify, received_date: object.created_date})
}, [object])
```

Comment: Won't this goes to infinite loop haven't it has chances because of the array deps and setNotify ? let me know your comments

Comment: Sorry but what is the question? This won't cause an infinite loop, cuz `notify` is not in the dependency array of the `useEffect`. That is why you have to pass a function to `setNotify(notify => ...)`

Comment: yep cool, i missed the array deps i got confused that it was the same object given as notify :)

Comment: your setNotify is missing `()` around the object you want to return. otherwise it will interpreter as block

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to do the reference

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [object, setObject] = useState({
    id: null,
    created_date: "2021-02-18",
    classroom: "",
    name: ""
  });

  const [notify, setNotify] = useState({
    id: 5,
    created_by: "1",
    notification: "object added",
    received_date: object.created_date
  });

  return <div>{notify.received_date}</div>;
}
```

Comment: you have posted the same answer twice

Comment: for  a sec site was down, so i didn't noticed may be twice i clicked on submit, thanks for notifying, removed the other :)

Comment: thank you soo much guys for your wonderful answers !! it helps me alot

Comment: @dreamboyachyut kindly vote and accept if it helped you so it will be helpful for future references , happy to help :)